# Determining a specific value from binary given a byte

Tags: c, binary, hex

I can determine a hexadecimal value per given byte by doing:

`hex = char & 0xff;`

For example, my `hex` value is `50`. This, in binary, would be `0011 0010`.

I am looking at 2^5 and 2^4 binary place, which value in my example above is `11`. Since this will be consistent regardless of hex value, how would I set my `binary` value to be equal to `11` (or to the 2^5 and 2^4 binary place)?

Comment: I'm not sure I get the question, you want to extract the value of those two bits?

Comment: @Hasturkun Yes. Outside the scope of this question, I could convert the value of those specific bits into a decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to mask and shift: first, create a binary "mask" that has ones in the positions that you want to keep; in your example, the mask would be `0x30`. Then apply binary "and" to the original number and the mask, and shift the result by the position of the smaller bit position (in this case, that's 4):

```
hex4and5 = (ch & 0x30) >> 4;
```

You can reverse the masking and shifting if it makes things easier for you:

```
hex4and5 = (ch >> 4) & 0x03; // Note that the mask is shifted, too
```

To make a mask from a list of bit positions, use binary "or" on expressions of `1 << pos`, where `pos` is the binary position of interest. For example, to build the mask for positions `4` and `5` use

```
int mask4and5 = (1 << 4) | (1 << 5);
```

Comment: You can use bit-fields too, but you must know the computer's architecture and compiler settings.

Comment: @EricJablow Thanks for the info. For my situation, the architecture and such is subject to change...so using bit-fields may not work for me.

Comment: C is a low-enough language that bit-fields would be a possibility. But they certainly aren't stable when dealing with architecture you cannot control.